# Drupal 7 - Add two menu items with the same path but different query string

Tags: nodes

On Drupal 7, there is a difficulty adding two or more items to a menu which are having the same URL but a different query string.

For example, when I add two similar paths:

1. node/add/alert?kind=regular
2. node/add/alert?kind=news

Only one of the links is randomly displayed. So frustrating...

Any ideas of how to by bypass this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did is add the [redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) module.

Then I created custom redirects for those menu items, e.g. "node/add/alert/kind/regular" goes to "node/add/alert?kind=regular".

No need for custom hook_menu programming. 
It worked! But why doesn't drupal provide it work out of the box???

Comment: oups wrong post...

Answer (score 2):

Another option would have been to make a custom Block in Drupal with your 2 links as simply an HTML list.

So far as I know `/node/add/alert` is 1 page in Drupal, Pylons, Joomla whatever .... its 1 page path to Apache or Nginx. The querystring is simply key-value pairs of arguments you are passing to the page.

The default Menu system in drupal doesnt allow for a single page to exist in more than 1 spot of your site (see [NodeSymlink](http://drupal.org/project/nodesymlinks) for a module that allows an alias of a page to live in different places of your site, but only 1 master location for the content).

I believe what you're seeing here is an example of drupal's 1 piece of content, lives only 1 place in drupal; so disallow multiple links to the same thing for SEO purposes.

Comment: Custom block was not an option - I had to put those links in the drupal admin_menu module which uses a standard drupal menu.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite with Drupal, but you can add a bit of jquery to target the menu item id.

In your menu item, set the path to "" as a placeholder.

Then add this bit of jquery:

$("a#specificLink1").attr('href','/node/add/alert?kind=regular');
$("a#specificLink2").attr('href','/node/add/alert?kind= news');